# Symfony 2 - How to validate Entity Field Type when it is populated using Ajax?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, validation

I am confronted to a problem that is driving me crazy for more than 3 days and I do not find any solutions. Nevertheless I found a post on stackoverflow that is EXCACTLY the problem I am facing. Unfortunately the person did manage to find a solution on his down but he or she did not shared it fully. As he explained it perfectly let just copy paste it here below:
By the way it seems that person who created that post only created his account for this problem and never came back since for other things. That it is why I allow myself to ask here again...

> I have 2 entities (A and B) with a Many to One relationship between
>   them.
>
> I create my form with the A entity and i use an entity field (dropdown
>   list) to display the rows in the B entity. I use a query builder to
>   filter them. If don't change the values in the list (ie. with ajax),
>   everything is working fine.
>
> But if I change dynamicly the values in the dropdown, when I submit
>   the form I have this error "This value is invalid"
>
> It's because the submitted value isn't included in the "array"
>   returned by the query builder.
>
> It seems that this validation is automatic in symfony for entity field
>   (I don't use any asserts on this field). I'd like to get rid of this.
>   But how ?

It seems that I need to implement Form Events. Unfortunatally I do not get it. I read the documentation which is very poor on that subject, read a lot of posts, searched on the Internet but did not found anything.

Here below my personal form type. What I do is the following. I create the first entity field type with the mapped property set to false and filter the entity just to get the departements. Then I create another entity type called localisation. By default I filter the entity to get nothing (''). What I do then to populate it is to use Jquery. But unfortunatelly I am confro,ted to the same problem as the other buddy (see above).

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Auth\GeoBundle\Form\LocalisationType;


class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('departement', 'entity', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'AuthGeoBundle:Localisation',
            'property' => 'departement',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->add('groupBy', 'e.departement')
                ;
            },
        ));


        $builder->add('localisation', 'entity', array(
            'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'AuthGeoBundle:Localisation',
            'property' => 'formLabel',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($dpt) {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.departement = :dpt')
                    ->setParameter('dpt', '')
                    ->add('orderBy', 'e.ville ASC')
                ;
            },
        ));

        //some other fields here...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'auth_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage to find a solution using the form events. I played with the "tutorial" at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html and got it working :) Here below the code I used in case somebody interested.

My formType:

```
<?php
//src/Auth/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php
namespace Auth\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Auth\GeoBundle\Form\LocalisationType;

use Auth\UserBundle\Form\EventListener\IsAdminFieldSubscriber;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        //NE PAS EFFACER -> exempled e comment ajouter un champ qui n'a rien à voir avec nos entitys
        //$builder->add("firstName", "text", array("mapped" => false));

        $builder->add('departement', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'AuthGeoBundle:Localisation',
            'property' => 'departement',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->add('groupBy', 'e.departement')
                ;
            },
        ));


        $dpt = "";
        $builder->add('localisation', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'AuthGeoBundle:Localisation',
            'property' => 'formLabel',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($dpt) {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.departement = :dpt')
                    ->setParameter('dpt', $dpt)
                    ->add('orderBy', 'e.ville ASC')
                ;
            },
        ));

        $builder->add('sexe', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_choice', array(
            'empty_value' => '',
            'choices'   => array(
                'homme'   => 'Homme',
                'femme' => 'Femme',
            ),
            'configs' => array(
                'minimumResultsForSearch' => 5,
            )
        ));

        $builder->add('date_naissance', 'date', array(
            'empty_value' => '',
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-small'),
            'years' => range(1900,2100),
            'months' => range(1,12),
            'days' => range(1,31),
        ));

        $builder->add('petit_mot');

        $subscriber = new IsAdminFieldSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'auth_user_registration';
    }
}
```

my EventListener:

```
<?php
//src/Auth/UserBundle/Form/EventListener/isAdminFieldSubscriber.php
namespace Auth\UserBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class IsAdminFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var FormFactoryInterface 
     */
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FormFactoryInterface $factory 
     */
    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Called before form data is set
     *
     * @param DataEvent $event
     */
    public function preBind(DataEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $dpt = $data['localisation'];

        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('localisation', 'entity', null, array(
            'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'AuthGeoBundle:Localisation',
            'property' => 'formLabel',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($dpt)  {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.id = :dpt_id')
                    ->setParameter('dpt_id', $dpt)
                    ->add('orderBy', 'e.ville ASC')
                ;
            },
        )));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You explain the problem yourself:

> "It's because the submitted value isn't included in the "array" returned by the query builder."

You can use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello Patt. First of all thank you very much for taking time to try to help me out. Give me some time to read the docs about Data Transformers and I will revert...

Comment: Hey Patt. I must say I am totally lost now. I read the doc and I do not get it... Is there to your knowledge another easier solution?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but your model data is an entity and your view data is a text (textbox poplated by ajax?). Therefore, you are submitting a value in an invalid format (text instead of entity). So, apply a transformer to 'localisation' and adapt the reverseTrabsform method. First do a var_dump on your value to confirm that it is a string. You can use your entity manager and transform you text in the same way as the doc mentioned above. Good luck!

Comment: No. I use entity type field so the output is in a select tag. Which is normal. And yes I populate that select via jquery and ajax.My problem is not the field type but the fact as you mentionned that the submitted value isn't included in the array (initial query_buildr query). So the validator is saying The value is not valid.